# Local Storage with login in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular8

I am using `angular8`. When I login using USER1 credentials and close the browser and login with `USER2` credentials. It still login with `USER1` credentials.

I have added the following code in app component it handled the above scenario but the issue is when I refresh the browser, the local storage gets cleared which I do not want. How can I handle that scenario?

```
import { Component, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Component({ selector: 'app-root', templateUrl:"./app/app.component.html" }) 
export class AppComponent  { 
    @HostListener("window:onbeforeunload",["$event"]) 
    clearLocalStorage(event) { 
    localStorage.clear(); 
    }
}
```

This Store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep the user logged in between page refreshes.

```
login(email, password) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${Constant.apiUrl}account/login`, { email, password })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            return user;
        }));    
}
```

Comment: You can Session Storage instead of local.

Comment: @stud3nt My use case is to use local storage for this. Is there no way this can be handled effeciently using local storage?

Comment: @EatPayBong Can you share how you store the credentials? I'm using `localStorage` to set my credentials too in my current project, but I don't have this problem as of now. Maybe if you share how you store it I can see how it works on your side.

Comment: @BelleZaid This is the way how I able to store credentials on local storage: 


```
 login(email, password) {
  
  return this.http.post<any>(`user/login`, { email, password })
      .pipe(map(user => {
        // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        return user;
      }
      ),
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener("window:onbeforeunload",["$event"])
```

The event you have used here is called upon the tab closing.
Consider not to bind this event and use a logout button instead, timeout or the combination of both.

Token invalidation should be happening by the server (eg. expiration) or by the user (via logout). This goes well with the general OAuth 2.0 flow.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this, the best way you can do is to not bind the clearing of `localStorage` with this `@HostListener("window:onbeforeunload",["$event"])`
The reason why the `localStorage` value gets cleared upon your refreshing of the page is due to this event triggering because before the page refresh and being loaded again, it will be unloaded first. Hence the reason why this event is called when you're refreshing the page and your `localStorage` values gets cleared.

As per what @NotMyDay has stated. You can opt with a logout button instead or a timeout. In addition, the token expiry set by the server. It's what I'm doing now currently.

Another thing you may want to do is, to cater to the user accidentally closing the window/tab and the user credentials is still available is to re-route it to the main page instead of the login page.

If you want to automatically logout after closing and you're afraid of having other user accessing the same computer, the best will be with `sessionStorage` then. As there is not much of an actual reliable window event handlers that can check for the window close. I've tried various method and the closest is with checking if the browser is refreshing or not with `!router.navigated` or `keypress` event in which the `e.keyCode == 116`(equals to button F5)